# MBed/Arduino RS-232 Serial communication issue

Tags: serial-port, arduino, mbed

I am receiving messages from a CAN interface into my mBed device. The mBed device then parses the information to send out on serial to another device. The information is sent out in the following format.

"< msg>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx< /msg>" where x = a hex number.

The other device receiving this message will receive the information split up in half (i've accounted for this in the code). The problem I'm having is, the messages will fall into the format ..... but there are times where the format is lost, for example:

```
[1]xxxx< /msg>< msg>xxxxx
[2]xxxxxxxx< msg>xxxxxxx
[3]< /msg>< msg>xxxxxxxxx
[4]xxx< /msg>< msg>xxxxxx
**Please ignore the space in the msg tag, it was necessary to show on StackOverflow'**
```

The baud rate set 38400bps on the mBed. I'm not using any parity, stop bit, start bit etc as I'm not too familiar with how they work. Can anyone help me how I might fix this loss in format, or am I going to have to include code in the receiving device to handle this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried reducing the baudrate, I think it could happen that your receiver is not able to process fast enough and this issue is arise cause of local buffering used in serial device. Otherwise you may have to write simple start and end marker alongwith length of message to receive correctly at receiver side.

Comment: can you explain to me what reducing the baud rate does, as far as I'm aware it just reduces the amount of bits transferred per second.

Comment: *"I'm not using any parity, stop bit, start bit etc as I'm not too familiar with how they work."* - Then you should learn how they work, and then set up the serial port accordingly.  These attributes are not optional parameters; they are required for proper configuration. Unless you don't want reliable serial communication. The issue you are having is called loss of message frame.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely normal, serial ports are not smart enough to recognize XML.  You will have to write the code yourself.  A basic algorithm is a state machine.  Declare a buffer that's large enough to store a complete message.  Then:

1. throw everything away you receive until you get '<'
2. store bytes you receive in the buffer until you get '>'
3. check that you got `<msg>`, back to state 1 if you did not
4. store bytes you receive in the buffer until you get '>'
5. check that you got `<msg/>`, back to state 1 if you did not
6. process the message, back to state 1

This ensures that you'll properly sync with the bus when you open the port and that you don't care how many bytes you receive in one read() call.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it doesn't recognise XML, the tag is just for differentiating between the start of the message and the end of the message.

When you refer to "Declare a buffer...." I assume you mean creating a buffer on the receiving device.

From what I can tell, the receiving method on the receiving device is called twice in order to receive the full 30 bytes of data. about 14 bytes on the first method and the remaining 16 on the second call. 

Thanks for your response!

Comment: The number of bytes you'll get is entirely unpredictable, it critically depends on timing.  Tends to fall into patterns but load the machine heavier or make changes in your code and it changes.  No, that buffer must exist in your code.  Just an array of bytes.

Comment: *"sync with the bus"*  -- A serial comm link is not a "bus".  The issue is synchronizing on the **message frame**.

Comment: CAN is an industrial bus.

Comment: True enough, but these messages are supposed to be generated by the mBed device, and not necessarily received over the CANbus.  It is the remote end of the serial link that loses message framing.  The OP implies that he prefers to not modify this *"other device"*.  Your answer seems to be a for that end of the link which has no CAN interface.